# PHP Composer autoload issue

Tags: php, class, composer-php

I want to autoload **class** via **PHP Composer** from file:

```
<?php
src/Product.php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class product
{

protected $id;


protected $name;


public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;
}
```

}

to file:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
require_once "bootstrap.php";
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$newProductName = $argv[1];

$product = new Product();
$product->setName($newProductName);

$entityManager->persist($product);
$entityManager->flush();

echo "Created Product with ID " . $product->getId() . "\n";
```

But I keep geting error:

php create_product.php ORM
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Product' not found in /home/vaclav/Server/vssk/VSSK/project/create_product.php:9
Stack trace: #0 {main}
  thrown in /home/vaclav/Server/vssk/VSSK/project/create_product.php on line 9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing two things:

1. A `namespace` in your src/Product.php file. Wrap the whole thing in a namespace for your app (something like `MyApp`)
2. Autoloading configured in `composer.json`:

   `"autoload": { "psr-4": { "MyApp\\": "src/" } }`

This will map the namespace `MyApp` to the src folder at the root of your project. Adjust it as needed.

Comment: Also don't forget to run `composer dump` as 3rd step to rebuild composer cache